# Using Unicode in php

Tags: php, unicode, dompdf

I wanted to enter some unicode characters in some pfd files generating in my project.These pdf are generated using data retrieve from the database according to the data given by the user. Can any one tell me how can I do this?
Um using XAMPP and Domdpf.  Can I store unicode characters in my database ?

Comment: Yes you can. Try it first and if you run into problems ask again with a specific problem and example code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647220/generating-pdf-document-with-unicode-characters-stored-in-the-database